# How to test if an array contains arrays? (Jest)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, npm-scripts, react-scripts

Given the following function:

```
chunk = (arr, n) => {
    return arr.reduce(function(p, cur, i) {
        (p[i/n|0] = p[i/n|0] || []).push(cur);
        return p;
    }, []);
}
```

I want to test if the output array contains arrays:

```
test("Splits a given array in N arrays", () => {
    let _input = Array.from({length: 999}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 999));;
    let int = mockService.getRandomArbitrary();
    expect(generalService.chunk(_input, int)).toContain(???????);
})
```

Considering [matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/using-matchers#arrays-and-iterables), how can one test if an array contains arrays?

Comment: You can check the array yourself and then see if your check is `true`. Something like `const condition = checkerArray.every(a => arrayOfArrays.some(array => ......))` and then `expect(condition).toBeTruthy()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly something like this?

We use `Array.isArray()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) here) to test each element

```
let output = generalService.chunk(_input, int));
let containArrays = true;
if (output.length) {
    output.forEach(element => {
        // containArrays is false if one of the element is *not* an array
        if (Array.isArray(element) === false) containArrays = false;
    });
}
// if output is an empty array it doesn't contain arrays
else containArrays = false;

expect(containArrays).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use *lodash* it's very easy

```
_.any(arr,function(a){
    return Array.isArray(a);
})
```